# Android call WCF service

Tags: android, wcf, web-services

I have a problem with calling `WCF web service` from `Android application`. If I call the following URL, `"http://10.0.2.2:80/WebService/WebServiceImpl.svc"` I get the response `"200 OK"`, but when I try to call the function within the service `"http://10.0.2.2:80/WebService/WebServiceImpl.svc/Test"` I get a response `"400 Bad request"`.

Can someone help?

```
namespace WebService
{
    public class WebServiceImpl : IWebServiceImpl
    {
        #region IRestServiceImpl Members
        public string Test()
        {
            return "Test pass";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

namespace WebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWebServiceImpl
    {
     [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET")]
        string Test();
    }
}
```

Android Activity:

```
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient  client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String SERVER_HOST="10.0.2.2";
        int SERVER_PORT = 80;
        String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/WebService/WebServiceImpl.svc/Test";
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, "http");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(target,request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            MessageBox(response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox("excepton");
            MessageBox(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void MessageBox(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: How does your config look like on the server? Does it have the webHttpBinding with the correct behaviour set ?

Answer (score 2):

I solve that using "SoapObject"

part of code:

```
public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/MyFirstPublishedWebService/WebServiceImpl.svc?wsdl";  
public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IWebServiceImpl/Login";
public static final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
    new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

envelope .dotNet = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Alex, Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly test this url in browser. if you have the same problem enable web access for your service in manifest.

Secondary check if ip 10.0.2.2 acceccable from your phone.